# dependent quantiles in R

Tags: r, quantile

I'm trying to make deciles for IDs and ***within those deciles*** of A form 4 quartiles of B for IDs. Hence the quartiles of B shall be dependent on deciles of A. Following is my attempt:

```
require(dplyr)
require(OneR)
foo <- data.frame(ID = 1:100,
                  A = runif(100, 50, 200),
                  B = runif(100, 50, 200),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
foo1<-foo %>%
  mutate(Aquantile = bin(A,nbins =  10,labels = c(1:10))) %>% 
  group_by(Aquantile) %>% 
  mutate(Bquantile = bin(B,nbins =  4,labels = c(1:4)))
foo1 <- foo1 %>% mutate(checkB = bin(B,nbins =  4,labels = c(1:4)))
```

However, the results in Bquantile is independent of Aquantile as can be seen in check variable. Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mutate()`does not offset the grouping. Therefore you get the same result in your second step. When providing no specific labels, you can guess the difference between the groups

```
foo1 <- foo %>%
  mutate(Aquantile = bin(A, 
                         nbins = 10, 
                         method = "content", 
                         labels = c(1:10)) %>% as.character()) %>% 
  group_by(Aquantile) %>% 
  mutate(Bquantile = bin(B, 
                         nbins =  4,
                         method = "content", 
                         labels = c(1:4)) %>% as.character())

is_grouped_df(foo1)
# [1] TRUE

foo1 %>% 
  mutate(checkB_grouped = bin(B, nbins = 4, labels = c(1:4))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(checkB_not_grouped = bin(B, nbins = 4, labels = c(1:4))) 

# A tibble: 100 x 7
      ID     A     B Aquantile Bquantile   checkB_grouped checkB_not_grouped
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>     <chr>       <fct>          <fct>             
 1     1 147.   78.9 7         (64.6,97.6] 1              1                 
 2     2  78.6 176.  2         (147,179]   4              4                 
 3     3 161.   96.9 8         (96.8,120]  1              2                 
 4     4 197.  149.  10        (126,161]   3              3                 
 5     5 164.  163.  8         (143,166]   3              4                 
 6     6 179.   65.5 9         (51.4,88.4] 1              1                 
 7     7  70.7 123.  2         (115,147]   3              2                 
 8     8  77.0  87.8 2         (82.6,115]  2              2                 
 9     9  91.9 100.  3         (86.6,108]  2              2                 
10    10  81.2 149.  3         (128,149]   4              3     

foo1 %>% 
  mutate(checkB_grouped = bin(B, nbins = 4)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(checkB_not_grouped = bin(B, nbins = 4)) 

# A tibble: 100 x 7
      ID     A     B Aquantile Bquantile   checkB_grouped checkB_not_grouped
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>     <chr>       <chr>          <fct>             
 1     1 147.   78.9 7         (64.6,97.6] (64.6,97.6]    (50.4,87.6]       
 2     2  78.6 176.  2         (147,179]   (147,179]      (162,199]         
 3     3 161.   96.9 8         (96.8,120]  (96.8,120]     (87.6,125]        
 4     4 197.  149.  10        (126,161]   (126,161]      (125,162]         
 5     5 164.  163.  8         (143,166]   (143,166]      (162,199]         
 6     6 179.   65.5 9         (51.4,88.4] (51.4,88.4]    (50.4,87.6]       
 7     7  70.7 123.  2         (115,147]   (115,147]      (87.6,125]        
 8     8  77.0  87.8 2         (82.6,115]  (82.6,115]     (87.6,125]        
 9     9  91.9 100.  3         (86.6,108]  (86.6,108]     (87.6,125]        
10    10  81.2 149.  3         (128,149]   (128,149]      (125,162]
```

Comment: Kindly help me make them dependent quartiles

Comment: They are dependent. Check whether your output matches your expectation

Comment: No, it doesn't match. I was expecting quartile labels in each decile. But check B , independent sort , has exactly same labels as Bquantile, which is supposed to be dependent sort.

Comment: because you apply the checkB onto a grouped df (`foo1`). The result differs if you apply it onto an ungrouped df. Check my updated code.

Comment: Why  checkB_grouped  & checkB_not_grouped  have same labels each decile? You can precisely see it when no labels are applied and Aquantile is arranged in ascending order.

Comment: cant replicate your results. it looks good to me. I include what I see above

Comment: Please give feedback about answers so the community knows whether the problem is solved or not

Comment: Apologies for belated reply. Thanks @wusel it works. However, can we also assign a unique identifier to each portfolios e.g. "4.3" for third quantile under 4th decile in a new column? Total unique identifiers shall sum up to 40. I'm looking forward to accept the answer.

Comment: This information is already present, isnt it? just add `paste0(Aquantile, ".", checkB_grouped)`

Comment: I'm getting 38 items only :(

Comment: Good question. Apparently it depends on the method of `bin`. I fixed it and thanks for the hint. Havent been aware of it either